# different login mechanisms in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

i'm a beginner to MVC 3 and has been given task to make login page in MVC, so for help i searched different ways to get around it but i saw some complicated codes like this:

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
   public int ID { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "Nome do Usuário")]
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite o Nome do Usuário.")]
   public string name { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "Senha")]
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite a Senha.")]
   public string password { get; set; }

 }
```

and for edit

```
public class EditViewModel
{
  public int ID { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Nome do Usuário")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite o Nome do Usuário.")]
  public string name { get; set; }

}
```

what is this ? why ? it confuses me, can i do it another way ?

Comment: Which part that you don't understand?

Comment: Why don't you start with some tutorials about ASP.NET MVC? http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

Comment: i did, but i saw simple codes like simple text boxes etc but this code confuse me especially 

[Display(Name = "Nome do Usuário")]
  [Required

Answer (score 0):

`[Display]` and `[Required]` are just data annotations. They're hints to other areas of MVC about how a property should be treated. Namely, `[Required]` tells the model binder to mark the model as invalid if that property has no value. So, if you have a form where the user fails to enter a value for that field, when you get to you `if (ModelState.IsValid)` block, it will fall through, returning the user to the form page with an error message. `[Display]`, just tells Razor how you'd like your property named when it generates things like labels for fields in a form.

Aside from that, the two classes you have there, are what's called view models. It's just a design pattern that many developers follow. Instead of using your entity (the model that's used with Entity Framework to represent a table in your database), you use specialized class that's customized for a view. This view model class only includes the properties of your entity that you need to work with and may and usually will contain additional properties no on your entity to hold things like select lists to feed to `DropDownListFor`, etc. You "map" (set properties on one based on the properties of the other) your entity to your view model and vice-versa.

Now, your question really shouldn't be "can I do it another way", using data annotations and view models are two things that actually make for good design. You just need to take the time to familiarize yourself with these and other concepts you find confusing. If you turn tail and run anytime something doesn't make perfect sense instantly, you'll never learn anything.